# is moq 4.0 stable enough?

Tags: moq

is moq 4.0 stable enough or should I just use 3.1?

Comment: I can't speak for 4.0, but 3.1 is very stable.

Comment: Unfortunately you don't define "enough" - which leaves quite a bit of room for variation.  For a private or small project, sure.  For a project which must live on for years under the scrutiny of an obsessive QA department - you don't want to be futzing around with (and blaming) the tools when something *odd* happens.

Answer (score 1):

I bet it's been well tested.

Comment: (sarcasm off) I'd use it if I were you.  I'm still using a much older version of MoQ but when I upgrade I won't be going to 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need a particular feature of 4.0, stick with 3.1 until 4.0 leaves beta.  You'll probably be fine if you jump aboard 4.0, but it you value your project and sanity, and have no compelling reason to move forward, then the stable line is the appropriate path.